# Rails - Delete a specific item only if the checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am trying to delete a tweet from my model only if the checkbox aside is checked.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the beginning of the code in my view:

```
<% @twits.each do |twit| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "#{twit.link}", twit_path(twit) %> | Engagement => <%= twit.engagement %> | <%= twit.like %> likes | <%= twit.retweet %> retweets | on <%= twit.first_date %>
    <%= check_box_tag("delete[#{twit.id}]",1) %> -
    <%= link_to twit_path(twit) do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
    <% end %> -
    <%= link_to twit_path(twit), method: :delete do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

EDIT => Here is my controller destroy action, very basic.

```
def destroy
 @twit.destroy
 redirect_to twits_path
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your controller? Am thinking your destroy action is missing.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi I just updated my post, thanks !

Comment: go with the JS suggested answer. But if you somewhat find yourself in situation to edit/delete multiple with checkbox, this video will put you on track.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Javascript for this. Assign `class` and `id` to delete link.

```
<%= link_to 'javascript:void(0);', class: 'delete-link', data: { id: "#{twit.id}" } do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
<% end %>
<%= link_to twit_path(twit), method: :delete, class: 'hidden', id: "twit_#{twit.id}" %>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.delete-link').on('click', function(e){
  var twit_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  if($("#delete_" + twit_id).is(':checked')){
    $("#twit_" + twit_id).trigger('click');
  }else{
    alert('Please check the checkbox!')
  }      
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the head up! As I do not master JS at all, where should I add the JS part? Thanks again!

Comment: Np, You can add that in `application.js` or your control specific js file.

Comment: I changed my view and added the JS code to `application.js`but it does not work.. Maybe am I doing something wrong

Comment: I mean I can still delete a tweet even if the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: Sorry @RSB it works, I have the popup with the alter. However, once I close the popup, the twit is still deleted. I'd like it not to be. Thanks

Comment: OK, I have edited the answer, make changes to the code accordingly, also add the above `css` code to `application.css`.